# React Apollo dynamically create query from state

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Heres a model situation
I have some fields in my DB lets say color,size,height ...

I can fetch and display these fields to user who can choose these fields and they are afterwards set to components state

What i want to achieve is to dynamically create GQL query **(not query variables)** from these fields stored in state

Example

```
//import react gql ....
class MyComponent extends Component {

constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     fields : []
   }
}

render(){
...
}

componentWillMount(){
    fetch(...)
      .then(fields => this.setState({fields}))
   }

}

export default graphql( --->state => CREATE_QUERY_DYNAMICALLY_FROM_FIELDS(state.fields)<----,{..some options})
```

**Is there a way to access components state during query creation ?**

**Or some other approach ?**

**Any ideas appreciated**

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in function for dynamically creating queries, but since the query is just a string you could format that string by yourself.
Eg: `\`query{ topLevelField { ${ fields.join(',') } }}\``
Also you should declare the list of fields outside of your react component, if you are going to declare the `graphql` query outside of your component.

Comment: Since ```graphql``` doesn't support dynamic queries, try to use the apollo client and inject the query conditionally or even the declarative [<Query .../>](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/why-apollo.html#declarative-data) Component.

Comment: @LefiTarik great comment i have upgraded to react-apollo 2.1 and with <Query> works like a charm if you write it as an answer i would definitely accept :)

Comment: great @Ziker :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **graphql** doesn't support *dynamic queries*, try to use the apollo client and inject the query conditionally or even you could use the declarative `<Query .../>` Component.

Comment: actually graphql **does** support dynamic queries (the query is simply sent as a json payload in the post). I am going to try what @a-moynet suggested working

Answer (score 5):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         fields : []
       }
   }

   render(){
   ...
   }

   componentWillMount(){
       const query = gql`
           query myDynamicQuery {
               viewer {
                   endpoint {
                       ${this.state.fields.join('\n')}
                   }
               }
           }
       `
       this.props.client.query({ query }).then((res) => ...)
   }
}
export default withApollo(MyComponent)
```

Hope this is working :)

Comment: Your suggestion works! In fact, the entire query can be dynamic. I do not know what downstream impact there might be (related to offline or subscriptions).