# GraphQL - Dynamically create shape of a query

Tags: javascript, graphql

Is there a package/methodology for dynamically creating a graphql query on the client-side?  For example, let's pretend that I have the following query

```
query { 
  foo {
    a
    b
    c {
      d {
        e
        f
      }
    g
  }
}
```

I want to allow the user to pick/choose what data fields get returned from that query.  In other words, if they do not want a field back, I would omit it from the query. * This is because some fields contain a very large amount of data and it would be better to avoid bandwidth issues if it can be avoided.

Do I have to build the query by hand (ugh) or is there a javascript tool out there that people use for this situation?

I saw this but it looks like it's no longer maintained and has some issues noted in the issues tab: https://github.com/codemeasandwich/graphql-query-builder

Answer (score 2):

You might have to build the query yourself (it's just a string, after all), in which case making use of the Builder pattern might help, since it seems like you have a complex set of parameters determining what should be included in the query.

Have you looked at these SO answers? Do these get at what you need?

[GraphQL dynamic query building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322346/graphql-dynamic-query-building)

[React Apollo dynamically create query from state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872538/react-apollo-dynamically-create-query-from-state) (if you're using React/Apollo)

One thing to keep in mind is that you lose some caching and security benefits by using dynamic, rather than static, client queries.

I would also suggest alerting your users that selecting certain fields will incur an expensive query; at the very least, paginate that data so that you're not returning such a large volume of it all at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks!  I don't think I want to use fragments as there could be 100s of possible results returned for a single query.  I like the idea of the dynamic one in the second link but I'm not sure that would account for recursively nested objects.  I already have paging so I am not sending back more data than is needed.