# Dynamic filter operator in GraphQL using Apollo (in a React app)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-boost

I'm using Apollo to make requests to my GraphQL server.

My query is like below:

```
export const QUERY_ITEMS = gql`
    query get_items($date: date) {
        items(where: {date: {_eq: $date}}) {
            name
        }
    }
`;

const {data} = useQuery(QUERY_ITEMS, variable: {date: '2020-01-01'});
```

Notice how right now the `_eq` operator is hardcoded. I'm implementing a feature where I'm making that operator dynamic to enable things like `'_gt'` and `'_lt'` .How can I achieve this?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952723/6124657

Answer (score 1):

`gql` can receive placeholder variable

> function gql(literals: any, ...placeholders: any[]): any;

so you can use something like this

```
export const QUERY_ITEMS = (placeholder) => gql`
    query get_items($date: date) {
        items(where: {date: {${placeholder}: $date}}) {
            name
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing in the date as a variable, you can pass in the entire expression

```
query get_items($exp: SomeType) {
  items(where: { date: $exp }) {
    name
  }
}
```

or the entire argument

```
query get_items($where: SomeOtherType) {
  items(where: $where) {
    name
  }
}
```

The types you use for your variable are schema-specific -- you can look up information about the schema Hasura generates in the GraphiQL interface available through the console (just search for the field name).